# Using Web Inspector to control mobile safari browser

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I know very little about web development and mobile development. I have been using Safari Web Inspector as a means to automate reloading a webpage on mobile Safari on an iPhone by using the keyboard commands for refresh from the web inspector window.

I am wondering if I can further control mobile Safari over my Mac by sending commands to visit a new website (possibly via the JavaScript terminal?). If this is possible, my goal would be to automate a script to visit a list of different websites in a row.

Are there any possible approaches to accomplish this in web inspector? Is there another avenue I should explore?